# Regex get all text before a string

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

In this [text](https://regex101.com/r/iQ4oQ5/6) I want to select all of it until this string :

```
IF EXIST %logfile% DEL %logfile%
```

How can I achieve this with a regex in Powershell?

Comment: I'm not sure I get you right .. but try this [`^(.*)(?=IF EXIST %logfile% DEL %logfile%)`](https://regex101.com/r/iQ4oQ5/2) And then `$1` is containing what you need.

Comment: it didn't work cause the test that I want to select containing returns to the line  [see here](https://regex101.com/r/iQ4oQ5/3)

Comment: ***"I have a text"*** ...

Comment: `(?s)^(.*)(?=IF EXIST %logfile% DEL %logfile%)`

Comment: What is the goal you are trying to accomplish?  This is simply a "How do I do something" when you'll get better answers if you list out what your goal is.

Comment: You might just get that part of a string with `$str.Substring(0, $str.IndexOf("IF EXIST %logfile% DEL %logfile%"))`

Comment: What I want to achieve is to replace all the text before that string by another text

Comment: @ZakariaBelghiti: The real text is larger, right? You just want to remove the part from the beginning till that piece of text?

Comment: Try `$newtext = "This is a new beginning.\`n\`n"` and then `$res = $newtext + $str.Substring($str.IndexOf("IF EXIST %logfile% DEL %logfile%"))`

Answer (score 2):

> I want to achieve is to replace all the text before that string by another text

You do not actually need any regex here, as the string you want to use a trailing delimiter is  a literal string. Just use `.Substring()`:

```
$str.Substring($str.IndexOf("IF EXIST %logfile% DEL %logfile%"))
```

This will get you the whole string from the first `"IF EXIST %logfile% DEL %logfile%"`.

Here is a demo:

```
$newtext = "This is a new beginning.`n`n"
$res = $newtext + $str.Substring($str.IndexOf("IF EXIST %logfile% DEL %logfile%"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"How IF EXIST %logfile% DEL %logfile% long the pattern is repeated." -replace ('IF EXIST %logfile% DEL %logfile%','replaced by this text $file')
```